# why zoom effects only applies to first image?

Tags: windows, image, video, ffmpeg

why zoom effects only applies to first image ?

> ffmpeg -i img%03d.jpeg -i 1.mp3 -vf
>   zoompan=z='zoom+0.002':d=25*5:s=1280x800 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264
>   -t 01:05:00 out12345.mp4

I have 3 images, 1 audio, and I am trying to create a video and expecting each image to have zoom effects.

Here is what I am getting, First image shows zoom effect then 2nd image shows up for a split second and then last image stays without any effect.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan what's full log ? that's the only command I am running and there are no logs

Comment: Run command and redirect stderr to a file. Paste or link to that.

Comment: @Gyan I am using windows, I am not sure what stderr is :S

Comment: Add `-y 2> zoompan.log` to the end of your command and run.

Comment: @Gyan here's the log - https://pastebin.com/v8BYY6BV

Comment: Your ffmpeg build is very old (~4 years). Some zoompan bugs have been fixed since then.

Comment: @Gyan I updated it to latest, but not much has changed, it only shows 2 images now, 1st one works with zoom and then 2nd one shows just like that - https://pastebin.com/ENkvcnKZ

Would it be possible to create 1 video per image with effects and then I concat all videos somehow perhaps

Comment: All your images are JPEGs of the same resolution and pixel format?

Comment: @Gyan no, they were not !!! but changing them to same resolution fixed the issue, thank you so much !!! add it as a answer and I will accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoompan filter operates per frame, so normally the command should produce the desired result i.e. each frame gets zoomed in over 125 frames.

However, when an image in the stream has different properties, the filtergraph is reinitialized, so a new zoompan instance is created, which starts on the changed frame as if starting from scratch. This new set of output has the same timestamps as already output frames so they are dropped.

There are two workarounds to prevent reinitialization:

1) make sure all frames in the input are uniform in properties

or

2) forcibly prevent reinitialization by adding `-reinit_filter 0` before the input. Only a few filters can handle frames with changing properties, so avoid doing this unless you are sure.